# Get Current Date filtered query through ASP.NET web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

In my program I need to filter Schedules which applicable to current month. I want json result bind with Jquery datatable. I created get method as follows

```
 public IEnumerable<ScheduleDto> GetSchedules()
    {
        return _context.Schedules
.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.PlannedStartDate.Date) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.DateTime.Now.Date))
                .Include(d => d.ResponsibleDepartment)
                .Include(e => e.EventCreatedBy)
                .Include(c => c.ScheduleCategory)
                .Include(y => y.ScheduleCriticality)
                .Include(v => v.EventEvaluatedBy)
                .Include(p=>p.Participants)
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<Schedule, ScheduleDto>);
    }
```

Its response with following error message

> "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

I did several suggestion given by Stackoverflow members. But problem still as it is. 
If anybody can find the error, I'm very much pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It just because I use `.Date` property in my query. Linq Engine not support with `Date` property. Therefore removing the `Date` property solved my error.

```
.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.PlannedStartDate).Value >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now).Value)
```

Thanks for all who spent time to resolve this.